# Laravel 6 | How do i make my last 4 posts show in index without messing up the page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am currently making a news site with laravel 6, but when i view the posts dynamically, the page gets all messed up.

[This is how it is supposed to look (this is static)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkKuj.png)

[And this is how it looks dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvNxi.png)

My index file with the error is as follows:

```html
@extends('layouts.layout')


@section('content')

    <section id="main-header">
        <div class="container mt-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="bg-black text-white text-center">
                        <h1>De Seneste Nyheder</h1>
                    </div>
                    @foreach($posts as $post)
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <a href="{{route('article', $post->id)}}">
                                        <img width="250" height="190" src="{{asset('img/1491602_w1.jpg')}}" alt=""
                                             class="card-img-top">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <h4 class="card-title">Inter Har Vundet CL!</h4>
                                    </a>

                                    <small class="text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Posted 20 minutes ago</small>
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        José Mourinho har fandme gjort det igen!. Inter er europæiske
                                        mestre
                                        igen efter 60 år!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="bg-black text-white text-center d-none d-lg-block">
                    <h1>Sponsor</h1>
                </div>
                <h1>Sponsor Her</h1>
                <br>
                <div class="card  d-none d-lg-block" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-header text-dark text-center">
                        Premier League Table
                    </div>
                    <table class="card-table table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Hold</th>
                            <th scope="col">K</th>
                            <th scope="col">P</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="bg-dark-blue">
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td><img height="25" width="25"
                                     src="https://dxugi372p6nmc.cloudfront.net/ronaldo/current/64x64/8650/teamlogo.png"
                                     alt="">
                                Liverpool
                            </td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="bg-dark-blue">
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td><img height="25" width="25"
                                     src="https://dxugi372p6nmc.cloudfront.net/ronaldo/current/64x64/8456/teamlogo.png"
                                     alt="">
                                Manchester City
                            </td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>48</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="bg-dark-blue">
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td><img height="25" width="25"
                                     src="https://dxugi372p6nmc.cloudfront.net/ronaldo/current/64x64/8197/teamlogo.png"
                                     alt="">
                                Leicester
                            </td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>45</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="bg-dark-blue">
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td><img height="25" width="25"
                                     src="https://dxugi372p6nmc.cloudfront.net/ronaldo/current/64x64/8455/teamlogo.png"
                                     alt="">
                                Chelsea
                            </td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>39</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="bg-dark-red">
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>
                                <small><img height="25" width="25"
                                            src="https://dxugi372p6nmc.cloudfront.net/ronaldo/current/64x64/10260/teamlogo.png"
                                            alt=""> Manchester United
                                </small>
                            </td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>34</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>Liverpool</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td>Liverpool</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>8</td>
                            <td>Liverpool</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>9</td>
                            <td>Liverpool</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>Liverpool</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </section>

    <section id="last-news">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-start mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-start">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
            </div>
    </section>

    <section id="latest_rumors_header">
        <div class="container mt-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="bg-black text-white text-center">
                        <h1>De Seneste Transfer Rygter</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 d-none d-lg-block">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="latest_rumors">
        <div class="container mb-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-img-caption">
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4 class="card-text bg-black-opacity text-white">Quaresma til Fenerbahce?</h4>
                                <img width="250" height="180" class="card-img-top"
                                     src="{{asset('img/quaresma-wme6-cover-Wcpu_cover.jpg')}}" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-img-caption">
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4 class="card-text bg-black-opacity text-white">Besiktas taler med Ronaldinho</h4>
                                <img width="250" height="180" class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('img/images.jpg')}}"
                                     alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-img-caption">
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4 class="card-text bg-black-opacity text-white">Besiktas taler med Ronaldinho</h4>
                                <img width="250" height="180" class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('img/images.jpg')}}"
                                     alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-img-caption">
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4 class="card-text bg-black-opacity text-white">Besiktas taler med Ronaldinho</h4>
                                <img width="250" height="180" class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('img/images.jpg')}}"
                                     alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </section>




@stop
```

And this is how it looks with static posts

```html
@extends('layouts.layout')


@section('content')

    <section id="main-header">
        <div class="container mt-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="bg-black text-white text-center">
                        <h1>De Seneste Nyheder</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="card">
                                <a href="#">
                                <img width="250" height="190" src="{{asset('img/1491602_w1.jpg')}}" alt=""
                                     class="card-img-top">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">Inter Har Vundet CL!</h4>
                                </a>

                                    <small class="text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Posted 20 minutes ago</small>
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        José Mourinho har fandme gjort det igen!. Inter er europæiske
                                        mestre
                                        igen efter 60 år!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img width="250" height="190" src="{{asset('img/1491602_w1.jpg')}}" alt=""
                                     class="card-img-top">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">Inter Har Vundet CL!</h4>
                                    <small class="text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Posted 20 minutes ago</small>
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        José Mourinho har fandme gjort det igen!. Inter er europæiske
                                        mestre
                                        igen efter 60 år!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img width="250" height="190" src="{{asset('img/1491602_w1.jpg')}}" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">Inter Har Vundet CL!</h4>
                                    <small class="text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Posted 20 minutes ago</small>
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        José Mourinho har fandme gjort det igen!. Inter er europæiske
                                        mestre
                                        igen efter 60 år!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img width="250" height="190" src="{{asset('img/1491602_w1.jpg')}}" alt="" class="card-img-top">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">Inter Har Vundet CL!</h4>
                                    <small class="text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> Posted 20 minutes ago</small>
                                    <p class="card-text">
                                        José Mourinho har fandme gjort det igen!. Inter er europæiske
                                        mestre
                                        igen efter 60 år!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="bg-black text-white text-center d-none d-lg-block">
                        <h1>Sponsor</h1>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Sponsor Her</h1>
                    <br>
                    <div class="card  d-none d-lg-block" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-header text-dark text-center">
                            Premier League Table
                        </div>
                        <table class="card-table table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">#</th>
                                <th scope="col">Hold</th>
                                <th scope="col">K</th>
                                <th scope="col">P</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr class="bg-dark-blue">
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td><img height="25" width="25"
                                         src="https://dxugi372p6nmc.cloudfront.net/ronaldo/current/64x64/8650/teamlogo.png"
                                         alt="">
                                    Liverpool
                                </td>
                                <td>22</td>
                                <td>64</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="bg-dark-blue">
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td><img height="25" width="25"
                                         src="https://dxugi372p6nmc.cloudfront.net/ronaldo/current/64x64/8456/teamlogo.png"
                                         alt="">
                                    Manchester City
                                </td>
                                <td>23</td>
                                <td>48</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="bg-dark-blue">
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td><img height="25" width="25"
                                         src="https://dxugi372p6nmc.cloudfront.net/ronaldo/current/64x64/8197/teamlogo.png"
                                         alt="">
                                    Leicester
                                </td>
                                <td>23</td>
                                <td>45</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="bg-dark-blue">
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td><img height="25" width="25"
                                         src="https://dxugi372p6nmc.cloudfront.net/ronaldo/current/64x64/8455/teamlogo.png"
                                         alt="">
                                    Chelsea
                                </td>
                                <td>23</td>
                                <td>39</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="bg-dark-red">
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>
                                    <small><img height="25" width="25"
                                                src="https://dxugi372p6nmc.cloudfront.net/ronaldo/current/64x64/10260/teamlogo.png"
                                                alt=""> Manchester United
                                    </small>
                                </td>
                                <td>23</td>
                                <td>34</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>6</td>
                                <td>Liverpool</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>64</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>7</td>
                                <td>Liverpool</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>64</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>8</td>
                                <td>Liverpool</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>64</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>9</td>
                                <td>Liverpool</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>64</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>10</td>
                                <td>Liverpool</td>
                                <td>20</td>
                                <td>64</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </section>

    <section id="last-news">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-start mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-start">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
            </div>
    </section>

    <section id="latest_rumors_header">
        <div class="container mt-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="bg-black text-white text-center">
                        <h1>De Seneste Transfer Rygter</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 d-none d-lg-block">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="latest_rumors">
        <div class="container mb-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-img-caption">
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4 class="card-text bg-black-opacity text-white">Quaresma til Fenerbahce?</h4>
                                <img width="250" height="180" class="card-img-top"
                                     src="{{asset('img/quaresma-wme6-cover-Wcpu_cover.jpg')}}" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-img-caption">
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4 class="card-text bg-black-opacity text-white">Besiktas taler med Ronaldinho</h4>
                                <img width="250" height="180" class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('img/images.jpg')}}"
                                     alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-img-caption">
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4 class="card-text bg-black-opacity text-white">Besiktas taler med Ronaldinho</h4>
                                <img width="250" height="180" class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('img/images.jpg')}}"
                                     alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-img-caption">
                            <a href="#">
                                <h4 class="card-text bg-black-opacity text-white">Besiktas taler med Ronaldinho</h4>
                                <img width="250" height="180" class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('img/images.jpg')}}"
                                     alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </section>




@stop
```

I don't really know what to right now. I am currently stuck. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Before first `@endforeach` you have two additional `</div>` which i think, should be after `@endforeach`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I missplaced the foreach loop. I started the foreach right before the card and ended it at one of the col-md-6